# ASP.NET MVC Core, Cannot see list in master details view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, master-detail

(First time!) Using ASP.NET CORE 2.0 MVC.  EF Db first.

I've searched loads of topics here and on the net and can't seem to find an answer to what I think is a simple 'master/details' VIEW question.

I have a view (no input entries, forms etc, jus read only view!) from a model that should show the master detail (Movie Title, summary) along with a list of its related scenes.  But the scene list is not showing anything so is the problem passing the linking Id Title ID to the list?

Here is my code:

Models:

```
 Movie.cs

public partial class Movie
{
    public Movie()
    {
        Scenes = new HashSet<Scene>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int TitleId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Year")]
    public int? TitleYear { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }       

    public ICollection<Scene> Scenes { get; set; }

}

 Scene.cs

public partial class Scene
{
    [Key]
    public int SceneId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TitleId")]
    public int? TitleId { get; set; } // foreign key from Movie
    public string LocationSite { get; set; }       
    public int? SceneOrder { get; set; }     

    public Movie Title { get; set; }
}
```

View (Details.cshtml)

```
@model MaltaMoviesMVCcore.Models.Movie

<h2>@Model.TitleAndYear()</h2>
<img src="@($"/images/titles/{@Model.TitleId}.jpg")" alt="@Model.Title" />

<br /><br />
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Summary)

<br /><br />

  <table class="table">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>
                  Scene Id
              </th>
              <th>
                  Scene Order
              </th>
              <th>
                  Location 
              </th>
              <th></th>                
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          @foreach (var item in Model.Scenes)
    {
      <tr>
          <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SceneId)
          </td>
          <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SceneOrder)
          </td>
          <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocationSite)
          </td>
      </tr>
}
      </tbody>
  </table>
<a asp-action="Index">Back to Movie List</a>
```

MovieController:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var movie = await _context.Movies
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.TitleId == id);
        if (movie == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(movie);
    }
```

Initial Id is passed from a previous movies list page via action link.

No errors given just no scene list displayed.  Am i missing something in the controller or at the foreach loop etc?

Would I benefit from using a ViewModel or partial view method which i did try but failed on both accounts.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query to fetch movie as shown below.

```
 var movie = await _context.Set<Movie>().Include(x => x.Scenes);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying.  No it didn't.

<Movies> is erroring...'Type or namespace 'Movies' not defined'

Comment: use Movie instead of Movies and add reference of that class there. If your current code works with Movies then this must work.

Comment: The error i'm getting now with the above line highlighted is...

"ICollection<Scene>>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IIncludableQueryable<Movie, ICollection<Scene>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"